# k8s securityContext bypass

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Running k8s 1.6 and in api-server, below is configured:

`--enable-admission-plugins SecurityContextDeny`

Is it possible to disable it for one pod or is there an exclusion list or override for a deployment.

I need to run a pod with:

```
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
```

Not able to figure it out, any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

No, this was a very limited system which is why PodSecurityPolicies were added in 1.8 to be a far more flexible version of the same idea.